# Jquery load function not working beginner

Tags: jquery, load

So wheni run this it's not working
Console log: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Filip/Desktop/load/demo_test.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

The "demo_text.txt" is:
"This is and external text!"

The come is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Filip ">
    <title>Site Name</title>
    <!--Title icone-->  
    <link rel="icon" href="http://www.axgig.com/images/97388478166848785489.png">
    <!--Bootstreap style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/    zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1 class="well">Jquery .load()</h1>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
                <button>Get External Content</button>
            </div>
    </div>

   <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
   ================================================== -->
   <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages   load faster -->
   <!--jQuery-->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!--Bootstrap Scripts-->
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/   eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <!--========Script fot this page========-->
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
        });
    });
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: so you want me to go to github and read the code, and find the mistake (without know what is the error) which mean, time consume for me =/...just post the question, and explain what happen, and what error/bug you are getting

Comment: Ty, sorry im 3 min new here =P brb  "edit" =D

Answer (score 0):

Please use Firefox xmlhttp request as chrome block such insecure content from loading